# I switched from postgres to a mysql database and get an error

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

After copying all the app files to the new app folder and installing MySQL through homebrew, I get this error message when trying to view the website.

```
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError in WelcomeController#index
Missing helper file helpers//users/froy_terriquez/desktop/projects/ram/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb
          class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
Rails.root: /Users/FroyTerriquez/Desktop/projects/ram
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Welcome Controller:

```
    class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
include ApplicationHelper

  def index
  end

  def contact
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.


  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Both Helpers:

```
module ApplicationHelper

end

module WelcomeHelper


end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also if you know of any informative links that would let me know what the correct process is for switching databases in a rails project that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your database.yml file to reflect your new database settings:

For example:

```
 development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_app_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:

 test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_app_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:


 production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: ymca_gym_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```